# Identificar objeto na imagem e cortar imagem em python

Tags: python, opencv

Olá, estou trabalhando em um projeto para fins cientifico. Neste projeto irei identificar pólen e classifica-los, para isso estou utilizando *opencv-python*. Eu até consigo treinar as imagens e fazer testes comparativos, porém tem um preparo das imagens que estou fazendo manualmente e quero automatizar. veja abaixo a imagem original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu a corto no local onde esta o pólen, porém faço manualmente. Veja abaixo como ela fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então só depois disso faço o treinamento e os testes. Gostaria de fazer esta identificação de forma automática. e cortar de forma automática. Então encontrei este método para tentar ajudar que deixa um circulo ao redor do pólen. Veja exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o formato não saiu de acordo, sendo assim sem sucesso! para isto utilizei o seguinte código:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_cinza, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100, param1=50, param2=14, minRadius=170, maxRadius=300)
```

Então gostaria de saber se é possível construir um código capaz de realizar o corte ao redor dos pólens. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você precisa segmentar a imagem primeiro. Diminuir o ruído e região a ser processada. Faça um contrates entre o fundo branco e as poles em preto, ou vice-versa. Logo depois disso o algoritmo de encontrar círculos vai ter mais facilidade pra entregar as regiões de interesse.

Comment: @gorn obrigado pela dica, fiz isto e melhorou meu resultado.